# Spaces in the Directory (for Terminal)

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have been trying to access my "My Development" folder from the terminal using the `cd` command, but it keeps returning `no such file or directory`. I assume that it is recognizing `My` as a command but I do not know how to go about this. How do I access the `My Development` folder with the `cd` command?

Note: I have tried `My-Development` and `My_Development` as alternates, they do not work.

**NOTE: The accepted solution is MORE EFFICIENT and overall BETTER than the other possible duplicate, which I also tried.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cd "My Development"`. The double quotes will do the job.
Space in bash is a separator for arguments and commands. So you will need to use single quotes or double quotes to tell bash it's one argument.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not know if it was possible. I will mark this as correct once it allows for an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to escape the space-

`cd My\ Development`